# Why I can't switch on this enum?

Tags: typescript

I have the following `enum` plus function that switch-case on it.

```
const enum ApplianceStatus {
  ONLINE = "Online",
  OFFLINE = "Offline",
  UNAVAILABLE = "Unavailable",
}
function getStatusColor(status: ApplianceStatus) : string {
  switch (status) {
    case status.ONLINE:
      return "list-group-item-success";
    case status.OFFLINE:
      return "list-group-item-danger";
    case status.UNAVAILABLE:
      return "list-group-item-warning";
  }
}
```

I'm getting a `Property '***' does not exist on type 'ApplianceStatus'`.

The same exact pattern for this other enum works instead:

```
const enum SupportedColor {
  BLUE = "Blue",
  YELLOW = "Yellow",
}

// no error here
function doSomething(supportedColor: SupportedColor): boolean {
  switch (supportedColor) {
    case SupportedColor.BLUE:
      return true;
    case SupportedColor.YELLOW:
      return true;
  }
}
```

I really can't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the name of the enum and not the variable `status`

e.g

```
enum ApplianceStatus {
  ONLINE = "Online",
  OFFLINE = "Offline",
  UNAVAILABLE = "Unavailable",
}

function getStatusColor(status: ApplianceStatus): string {
  switch (status) {
    case ApplianceStatus.ONLINE:
      return "list-group-item-success";
    case ApplianceStatus.OFFLINE:
      return "list-group-item-danger";
    case ApplianceStatus.UNAVAILABLE:
      return "list-group-item-warning";
  }
}
```

**note**: you don't have to add `const` to your enum ([link to official doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html))

To go a bit further:

You are not even force to use a switch case, you can use a dict to be slightly more efficient (as the dict is initialised only once)

```
enum ApplianceStatus {
  ONLINE = "Online",
  OFFLINE = "Offline",
  UNAVAILABLE = "Unavailable",
}

const statusColorMap: { [key in ApplianceStatus]: string } = {
  [ApplianceStatus.ONLINE]: "list-group-item-success",
  [ApplianceStatus.OFFLINE]: "list-group-item-danger",
  [ApplianceStatus.UNAVAILABLE]: "list-group-item-warning",
};

const getStatusColor = (status: ApplianceStatus): string => statusColorMap[status];
```

Answer (score 1):

in the first situation, you are accessing an instance field, i.e. status.ONLINE.
So basically it's like you are accessing ONLINE.ONLINE.
You need to access the enum as you did in the second case: ApplianceStatus.ONLINE, etc.

Comment: I totally kept missreading since the only difference was the 's' 'S'. Thanks.